# Sympy Solver returing and expression

Tags: sympy, solver, determinants

So I'm taking the determinant of a matrix, then trying to use the Solver in Sympy to solve the expression for a particular variable.

The determinant I am trying to solve while being pretty complicated only has this one variable in it. Being a long expression I don't want to paste it all in but I've shortened it to a snippit that gives the same result;

```
Determinant = -0.0134365566406344*Nperp**7*sqrt(Nperp**2 + 0.3249)/(3.07787011388119*Nperp**2*sqrt(3.07787011388119*Nperp**2 + 1) + sqrt(3.07787011388119*Nperp**2 + 1)) - 4.2064522609332*Nperp**6/(3.07787011388119*Nperp**2 + 1)

Solutions = solve(Determinant, Nperp**2)
```

The problem is that when I print Solutions, I get an expression back in terms on Nperp instead of a numerical solution which is what I want.

I'm not sure whether the problem is that Sympy cannot handle the high powers in the polynomial, or if maybe there is no numerical solution possible but I would appreciate some thoughts of people more knowledgeable than I.

Thanks!

Edit: Code not indented

Comment: The code snippet includes quantities like `Nperp7` and `Nperp6`. Is this correct?

Comment: They should be 'To the power of' I'm not sure why the ** got removed since I copied it straight from my script but I'll edit it, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: It was due to me not indenting the code :)

Comment: Try `solve(Determinant, Nperp)`

Comment: That does actually solve the problem, my thanks!

Comment: How do I label your comment as a solution? I think that's what I need to looking at other posts.

Comment: You can only *accept* (and *upvote*) an answer if you find it useful. This does not apply to comments, which is reasonable since they do not require any significant effort from the poster. Thanks for your consideration though!

Answer (score 1):

You are solving for `Nperp**2`. The answers it gives you are correct: they do equal `Nperp**2` according to your Determinant equation, but it's probably not what you want. If you give `solve` an expression, rather than a single symbol, it will just isolate that expression.

You are probably looking for

```
Solutions = solve(Determinant, Nperp)
```

For me, this gives two solutions, `[-549.228571428573, 0.0]`.